# Obter conteúdo que está antes do número usando regex

Tags: php, string, regex

```
$MinhaString = "Aventura, Fantasia, Ação 25 de maio a 31 de maio"
```

Tentei fazer assim, só que não funciona.

```
$Genero = strstr ($MinhaString,"/[^0-9]/",true);
```

Preciso apenas do "Aventura, Fantasia, Ação". A data não é estática.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso usando o método preg_match

```
preg_match('/^([^0-9]+).*/', "Aventura, Fantasia, Ação 25 de maio a 31 de maio", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

A regex '/([^0-9]+).*/' vai pegar todos os caracteres não numerais antes do primeiro número.
Na sua tentativa você esqueceu de colocar na regex o match para o resto da string.

Comment: Eu ainda poria o âncora antes do conjunto. Mais sobre o assunto : http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/ancoras.html#2_3

Comment: Alterei para incluir a ancora no começo da string.

Comment: sua regex já funcionaria sem o método preg_match amigo!

Answer (score 2):

Essa regex vai funcionar, ela captura todo o conteúdo não numérico do início da linha até a primeira ocorrência de um dígito.

```
^\D*(?=\d)
```

Explicação:

- `^` indica o início da linha.
- `\D*` faz a regex capturar todos os caracteres não numéricos de forma *greedy*.
- `(?=\d)` isso é um positive lookahead com dígito, indica que só deve capturar o `\D*` se houver um dígito depois do grupo de captura e nesse caso já faz a regex parar a captura.

Troque sua RegEx por essa e vai funcionar.

Aqui tem um [teste](https://regex101.com/r/3sp1kv/1)